# Boot2Docker doesn't recognize "sudo", "tce-load"

Tags: docker, sudo, boot2docker

I'm running Boot2Docker on Windows 7 (64 bit).  Boot2Docker is supposed to be based on Tiny Core.  I was trying to install docker-compose (a separate issue that I'm still working on), and several help topics (such as [How to install docker-compose on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289785/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-windows)) suggested using commands involving both `sudo` and `tce-load`.  Boot2Docker gives `error:command not found` when I try to use these commands.  I've poked around in the /bin folder and sure enough, neither has a file.  Other commands that I can use correctly, like the usual `ls`, `cd`, `rm`, etc., exist in the /bin folder.  Even if Boot2Docker for some reason took out tce-load from Tiny Core (although most help posts show it working), sudo should still exist in a unix environment, no?

Is there something I need to download/install first before these commands would be available normally, or is there something going on with Boot2Docker?  I'm new with using VMs so it could be something simple.  I tried reinstalling and that did nothing.  I've searched a lot of help topics related to docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, tiny core, and I haven't found anything.

Comment: I believe sudo won't work because user permission on Windows doesn't work like that. A ls command are easy to port, it's an alias to dir, but sudo isn't. For example, you can't switch in command shell to other user context. (i.e. logout and login using another credential).

Comment: What version of Boot2Docker are you using?  Just checked mine and tce-load is there under /usr/bin/tce-load  I am using boot2docker 1.5.0 on MacOS

Comment: for exactly this reason, as well as to have a proper docker platform, I'm using CoreOS VM in HyperV, tcl is a waste of time. Here's a great repo to get you started: https://github.com/paulshir/coreos-hyperv

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, someone at work helped fix the issue in about two minutes.  I felt a little dumb, as the solution (below) was very simple.  For the record I am using Boot2Docker 1.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out all I needed to do was run Boot2Docker then **type `boot2docker ssh`.**  This actually connects to the Unix VM, instead of running docker commands from a Windows shell.

Comment: type boot2docker ssh ? where? when? who? why?